# How to Repeat a background image in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Using CSS i can use the background repeat property to repeat an image across the page . How do i do that same thing in silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight does not natively support it, but nothing stopping you creating a user control that does the same thing.

Found [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54147/ExImage-A-Silverlight-control-very-similar-to-the) with a quick Google search. *The advantage of using a user control is that if better methods are found to do this you only need to change your one control* :)

Answer (score -1):

Silverlight is NOT the same as HTML/CSS. You going to have to create an image control wherever you want to use it and set the source. If you really know what your doing you can set the source of one image control and bind all the other image controls to it.

Comment: However downvoted me obviously knows nothing about Silverlight